# Как узнать насколько быстро работает?

Tags: php

Привет, как хобби, для себя делаю (велосипед) CMS'ку, фреймворки не использую, но за основу взято MVC с единой точкой входа и сохранение данных(контента) в mysql + небольшой модуль подобный opencart.

Собственно вопрос, как узнать насколько быстро это чудо работает (скажем соотнести с `joomla, wordpress`)? Сделал таким образом:

```
$time_start = microtime(1);
$memory_start = memory_get_usage();
```

и в конце тоже самое, потом отнимаю значения, результат на моем сервере:

```
//на 1000 итераций цикла с моим кодом:
0.050467014312744
121496

//на миллион итераций уже:
Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

конфиг сервера:

```
CPU: Xeon E3-1230
RAM: 8 Гб
OS:  Centos 6.2
```

Так вот, дорогие профессионалы, реально ли сказать "насколько это быстро" и потянет ли сие чудо, скажем трафик 5000 \ сутки на таком сервере?

И в общем как примерно это рассчитать или может кто посоветует что почитать по этому поводу или поделится ключевыми знаниями.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Исходя из того, что 1000 итераций занимают 0.05 секунды, легко предположить, что миллион должен работать 50 секунд. А учитывая, что большинство apache+php настроено так, что они отрубают скрипт за 30 секунд, то результат ожидаемый.

Хватит ли этого на 5000 пользователей в сутки? считаем. 5000 страниц будет сгенерировано за  0.05*5 = 0.25 секунд. То есть, если все ломанутся одновременно, то за одну секунду контент для них будет сгенерирован. С точки зрения клиента вполне себе хорошо.

Но Вы забываете об одном - код то бегает в сферическом вакууме - то есть в цикле. А в реальной жизни есть ещё накладные расходы на сеть, на память, выделяемую для каждого клиента.

Я советую взять утилиты ab, которая является частью апача и потесить ею. [Ссылка на описание](http://www.ashep.org/2011/nagruzochnoe-testirovanie-web-servera/). 
А также потестировать другой движок, который выполняет аналогичное Вашему. А там будет видно. Только тестируйте на своем сервере!

Comment: Репа @KoVadim говорит сама за себя... Хороший ответ!